# How to add a public CA file in the truststore format without any private key to karate framework for SSL verification?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, karate

Can anyone please help me understand how I can add a CA.crt file without any private key to karate , in which format? I am not being able to convert the CA.crt file into JKS/PKCS12/PKCS11 due to the lack of private key. Its a public cert and working when I am firing the api in Postman with SSL verification on.

I tried to use openssl to convert the .crt to .p12 file following the command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in sapCA.crt -out cert.p12
```

However, it is showing the following error:

```
Could not read private key from -in file from sapCA.crt
```

I tried to force download the CA file in jks format and run my feature file.
This is my feature file:

```
 Scenario: To get the api authenticated- to execute the api with client credential.  
    
    * configure ssl = {trustStore:'C:\\Users\\Certificates\\Root CA.jks',trustStoreType: 'jks'}
    Given url baseUrl
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    * print response
```

However, in karate its showing the following error:

```
src.test.java.features.firsttest: firsttest.feature:14 - java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

Comment: no one has reported this before so it sounds like you are missing something. I have a feeling windows paths like what you are using won't work. try keeping the files side-by-side with your tests to troubleshoot. besides asking you to "read the docs" I don't have any other advice right now. karate is open-source and contributions are welcome